# original email body content changing issue in asp.net using iframe

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iframe, lotus-notes

I'm displaying .eml file(*Lotus Notes email files*) in asp.net webpage using `iframe` tag, and the email body is not displaying as in the original format for non-English (German, Dutch, French, etc.) languages.

Original content is changing and some special characters are coming in between words.

**Example:**

**Original Content:**

[image]

**iframe Content:**

[image]

Please help with the solution.

Comment: Does your page/iframe use the UTF-8 ?

Comment: yes i tried all charset, example -  content="text/html; charset=utf-8", content="text/html;charset=message/rfc822", content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-15". but didn't work any of these.

Comment: How are you creating the .eml files? Lotus Notes normally stores data in .nsf files and the internal format uses a non-standard charset called LMBCS. If the conversion to .eml did not account for that, you will have to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: when we save(Ctrl+S) email in lotus notes it will save in .eml extension. (in outlook it's .msg extension).

Comment: If you look at the eml  file with your favorite text editor, you'll notice that the text is already encoded. You probably need to decode the lmbcs codes when you load the eml file

Answer (score 0):

Try changing a language of the iframe

Renaming the file to `*.mht` and opening it in iframe should work too